# Update a widget if the screen is selected

Tags: android, widget

I try to build a widget with the following behavior: Only update if the widget is shown. 
Let me explain a little bit more about it. Assume that the smartphone have maybe 3 home screens, one, two and three. The widget will placed on screen 3, if you activate your smartphone it will start on screen 1. So, I only want to update the widget if the screen is changed to screen 3 by the user, I want to react on this event. Is there any chance in android to do this?

As far as I see there is unfortunately no way to do this, there is no change to get informed about a visibility change or something similar. I look for hours with Google but don’t find any interesting stuff. Does someone have other information? I’m glad to any hint; hope you can help me out.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dispatchTouchEvent (Hope you can get the x,y coordinates of the view to be checked.)

Steps :

1. let containerView be the view which contains your view.
2. set an ontouchlistener for your view.
3. When the screen changes or at the time you need to check whether the view is visible, initiate a dispatchTouchEvent call with MotionEvent containing the coordinates of your view.
4. if your view is there in that coordinate area, the touch event for your view will get called.

For example :

```
    containerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setContentView(containerView);
            yourView = containerView.findViewById(R.id.yourView);
            yourView .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "View visible",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When you need to check, do following code :

```
public void doCheck() {
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
    float x = 100f; //yourView x coordinate
    float y = 100f; //yourView y coordinate
    int metaState = 0;
    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, metaState);
    containerView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: I don’t think I can change anything on the normal home screen, can I? With home screen I mean the normal screens you see if you start your smartphone. I don’t want to replace them with an own implementation just to send me an event…